# iAD is obscured by UITableView Indices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, iad

I have a UITableView and I'm adding an iAD as a footer view at the bottom of the screen added to a UITableView.

The iAD is effectively pinned there since I update the iAD's position whenever the screen is scrolled with -(void)viewDidScroll...

However, since my UITableView is full of indexes, the indexes for some reason, appear IN FRONT of the iAD, effectively blocking it! The rest of the UITableView works fine, with the UITableViewCells appearing behind the iAD.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a tutorial that implements the iad in the bottom of the screen in uitableview, hope it helps. Adrian
http://www.ioslearner.com/implement-iads-tutorial-iphone-ipad-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You can try resizing the TableView and place it over iAD Frame, so that they dont overlap each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the iAd in a fixed section of the table view. Alternatively I would just size the tableview (in interface builder or whatever) to make space for the iAd at the bottom.